# How can i Join, GroupBy and Select with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to perform Join, GroupBy two columns and select to a new list as

```
            var v = master.Join(
                detail,
                o => o.Id,
                d => d.OrderId,
                (o, d) => new 
                {
                    DateAdded = o.DateAdded,
                    VatRate = d.VatRatePercentage,
                    InvoiceDescription = o.InvoiceDescription
                }).GroupBy(c => new
                {
                    c.DateAdded,
                    c.VatRate
                })
                .Select(gcs => new 
                {
                    DateAdded = gcs.Key.DateAdded.Date,
                    VatRate = gcs.Key.VatRate,
                    InvoiceTypeDescription = gcs.Key.InvoiceDescription,
                }
                ).ToList();
```

but i get the error

```
'<anonymous type: DateTime DateAdded, decimal VatRate>' does not contain a definition for 'InvoiceTypeDescription' and no accessible extension method 'InvoiceTypeDescription' accepting a first argument of type '<anonymous type: DateTime DateAdded, decimal VatRate>' could be found
```

I would like to group by two columns (DateAdded, VatRate) but get the InvoiceDescription column also in the results. How can i fix that?

Comment: Do you realise that `gcs` is a _group_ of things with the same `DateAdded` and `VatRate`, but could have different `InvoiceDescription`s? Now knowing that, _which_ `InvoiceDescription` do you want from each group?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I would love to have the invoice description from the join result, before the GroupBy clause

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs? It doesn't make sense to "have the invoice description from the join result" in the `Select` clause, is what I am saying.

Answer (score 3):

This is a sample:

```cs
var resultmutiplekeylambaorderbyelement = studentlist  
    .GroupBy(stu => new{stu.standard, stu.age})  
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key.standard).ThenBy(y=> y.Key.age)  
    .Select(g => new { standardkey = g.Key.standard, agekey = g.Key.age, studentobj = g.OrderBy(y => y.name) });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).